# multiple UIDatePicker one uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

In my `ViewController` there are several `UiTextfield`.

I intend to use a single `UIDatePicker` that is expected to respond accordingly.
my code only responds to event generated by second textfield and not the first one.

I just need to determine which `UITextField` has generated the event...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

var datePicker = UIDatePicker()

@IBOutlet weak var tvDueDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tvOtherDate: UITextField!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     //setupDatePicker()
     self.tvDueDate.tag = 0
     self.tvOtherDate.tag = 1
     //setupDatePicker(textField)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    setupDatePicker(textField)

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    setupDatePicker(textField)

}




func setupDatePicker(text: UITextField) {
    // Sets up the "button"
    //tvDueDate.text = "Pick a due date"
    //tvDueDate.textAlignment = .Center
    // Removes the indicator of the UITextField
    //tvDueDate.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    // Specifies intput type
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
    // Creates the toolbar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Adds the buttons
    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "doneClick")
    var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "cancelClick")
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    // Adds the toolbar to the view
    if text.tag == 0{
        self.tvDueDate.inputView = datePicker
        self.tvDueDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    else
    {
       self.tvOtherDate.inputView = datePicker
        self.tvOtherDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

}

func doneClick() {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    if tvDueDate.isFirstResponder(){
        tvDueDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
        tvDueDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }else{
      tvOtherDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
       tvOtherDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

func cancelClick() {
    if tvDueDate.isFirstResponder(){
          tvDueDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }else{
         tvOtherDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give unique tags to your UITextFields and use UITextField delegates.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     //setupDatePicker()
     self.tvDueDate.tag = 0
     self.tvOtherDate.tag = 1

 self.tvDueDate.delegate = self
 self.tvOtherDate.delegate = self
 //setupDatePicker(textField)
 }
// UITextField Delegates
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
 println("TextField did begin editing method called")

if textField.tag == 0
..........
if textField.tag == 2
....
 }
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
 println("TextField did end editing method called")
 }
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
 println("TextField should begin editing method called")
 return true;
 }
```

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev....Thanks for the concern......my delegate methods dont seem to work......maybe i am not using tags properly.....could you forward me a reference...I have even edited my code and posted it above as you explained

Comment: In your viewdid load you need your_txt_field.delegate = self

Comment: answer edited, You can give tags and connect UITextField delegates in IB too.

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev.......Thank you for replying .....after adding the delegate it worked.............

Comment: Welcome @CloyMonis .. plz accept, whenever an answer helps you to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
setupDatePicker()
```

From viewDidLoad and your code is

```
if tvDueDate.isFirstResponder(){
        tvDueDate.inputView = datePicker
        tvDueDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    else
    {
        tvOtherDate.inputView = datePicker
        tvOtherDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
```

adds picker as inputAccessoryView . As at the point of viewDidLoad no text field is FirstResponder that's why only your else part is excited and its only added to tvOtherDate field.
I would recommend to call it from the textfield delegate method (will begin editing or didbegineditting) or call it on tap. And to check from which it is called also pass the textfield or you can use tag.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Delegates and tags to my UiTextField helped me.......

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

var datePicker = UIDatePicker()

@IBOutlet weak var tvDueDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tvOtherDate: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //setupDatePicker()
    self.tvDueDate.tag = 0
    self.tvOtherDate.tag = 1
    //setupDatePicker(textField)

    self.tvDueDate.delegate = self
    self.tvOtherDate.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    setupDatePicker(textField)

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    setupDatePicker(textField)

}

func setupDatePicker(text: UITextField) {
    // Sets up the "button"
    //tvDueDate.text = "Pick a due date"
    //tvDueDate.textAlignment = .Center
    // Removes the indicator of the UITextField
    //tvDueDate.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    // Specifies intput type
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
    // Creates the toolbar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Adds the buttons
    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "doneClick")
    var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "cancelClick")
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    // Adds the toolbar to the view
    if text.tag == 0{
        self.tvDueDate.inputView = datePicker
        self.tvDueDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    else
    {
        self.tvOtherDate.inputView = datePicker
        self.tvOtherDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

}

func doneClick() {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    if tvDueDate.isFirstResponder(){
        tvDueDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
        tvDueDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }else{
        tvOtherDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
        tvOtherDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

func cancelClick() {
    if tvDueDate.isFirstResponder(){
        tvDueDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }else{
        tvOtherDate.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
}
```